# Map audience-readable-description to cryptic description in ODBC query

Tags: excel, odbc, pivot-table

Data from an external database will be used to create an excel bar chart.

The database is accessed via odbc.  One of the columns has data which is one of 50+ different 'classifications'.  Many of these classifications are cryptic variable names which would not make sense to an audience.  In addition over time the 'categories' have grown so now there are 3 or 4 different 'categories' that actually mean the same thing.

I do not have the ability to add a table to the database that would allow me to map a Audience-readable-name to each 'category'.

for example Turquoise, Cyan, and Azure could all be mapped to "BLUE"

I would appreciate suggestions on how to handle this mapping in excel or SQL without adding a table to the database.

Answer (score 0):

in the excel doc with the bar chart, create a worksheet with two columns to produce your map

in sheet2 cols A and B would contain...

```
      AZURE      Blue
      CYAN       Blue
      TURQUOISE  Blue
```

and then add a column in the imported data that uses this map to transform the imported values

in the first cell in row 2 of this new column Z, and assuming your imported Categories is in column B, insert this formula

```
=VLOOKUP(B2;Sheet2!$A$1:$B$3;2;FALSE)
```

which returns Blue if B2 contains AZURE, and N/A if B2 is not in the conversion table. To alleviate this rude behavior, add some ISNA checking...

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(B2;Sheet2!$A$1:$B$3;2;FALSE));B2;VLOOKUP(B2;Sheet2!$A$1:$B$3;2;FALSE))
```

Comment: Checking if I understand your solution:  1)  Create a new sheet and import all the ODBC data into the sheet 2) add a new column with a formula to do the mapping.  If the barchart is to update automatically will a macro or VB code be needed to set the data range or is there a more elegant way of handing?  I was hoping  that there was a SQL statement that would perform the mapping.

Comment: (1) yes. (2) yes. (3) for only once solution, copy the new column "as values" into a second new column, and then copy this second new column over the original "categories" column. (4) for a repeatable solution, automate the steps in (3) with a recorded macro.